# Removing rejected applications from iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I have a rejected app in iTunesConnect and I was wondering if there is a way to delete these binaries so they no longer appear in my iTunesConnect apps dashboard, anybody find a way to do this? I have not been able to find a clear answer.

Comment: Don't think apple provides a way to delete uploaded binaries, can't you just increase version an upload a new one? Not saying it wouldn't be useful to delete binaries not published to the store yet but itunes connect was always very inflexible in relation to this

Comment: I have been doing that for a while now but I have a few rejected ones that have new versions already in the app store and are just sitting and can not be used as I will not be updating one of my applications anymore.

Comment: Expanding on Claudio's comment, removal of versions was disabled more than one year ago. It was possible before, so the only thing you could try is contacting Apple directly.